# Can't run in subfolder Laravel Horizon

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am running my Laravel project in subfolder under domain. So far everything is normal. I add job queues by installing Horizon, but horizon works directly on domain, not in subfolder.

my project: example.com/new

Horizon: example.com/new/horizon

when i click it, horizon comes as example.com/horizon and paths like horizon/api/stats , horizon/api/masters, horizon/api/workload fall into 404 error.

```
When I look at the console, I get errors like GET example.com/horizon/api/stats 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at t.exports (app.js?id=9db6ba6424a3d1048c194c9c1e4429fe:2:5360)
    at t.exports (app.js?id=9db6ba6424a3d1048c194c9c1e4429fe:2:7772)
    at XMLHttpRequest.v (app.js?id=9db6ba6424a3d1048c194c9c1e4429fe:2:712)
```

In the **config/horizon.php** file;

`'path' => 'horizon',` i get an error when I change the path to `'path' => 'new/horizon',`

Laravel version 8.x and Centos7 installed. How can i run Horizon in subfolder?

Comment: What is the error you get? And why do you have Laravel on `example.com/folder`? Laravel is not going to work correctly, you must use a subdomain or a domain, you will have lot of issues like this...

Comment: So Laravel won't run in subfolder? i'm just learning this! Actually it seems to be working fine now, but horizon wants to point to the main domain. When I look at the console, I get errors like GET example.com/horizon/api/stats 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Yeah, you may be able to "tweak" Laravel to let the framework work on a subfolder, but the framework uses the domain as the main route, as Laravel is a framework for serving webs, so why would you "use" it only on a subfolder? Remember you can do `Route::get('/test', ...);` that is going to be `example.com/test`, so Laravel is already handling absolute URLs (not subfolders)

Comment: then it won't be a problem if I run it in a subdomain. is it true?

Comment: that is true, you will have no issues